# Add and remove the class in the link d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How can i add and remove the class in the link in the force layout. Consider if my `d.source.x  == d.target.x` then i have to add class else i have to remove the class from link.

```
path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var x1 = d.source.x,
        y1 = d.source.y,
        x2 = d.target.x,
        y2 = d.target.y,
        dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1),
        dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
        dr = dx * dx + dy * dy;

    var rotation = 0;
    if (x1 === x2) {

        var dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) / 1.8; // note that this is always equal to Math.abs(dy)
        var sweep = 1;
        if (y1 > y2) {
            sweep = 0;

        }

        return "M" +
            d.source.x + "," + d.source.y +
            "A" + dr + "," + dr +
            " 0, 0" + sweep + " " +
            d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }



    return "M" +
        d.source.x + "," +
        d.source.y + "A" +
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
        d.target.x + "," +
        d.target.y;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use d3 classed operator.

```
if(d.source.x == d.target.x){
   d3.select(this).classed("your-class-name",true); //Adding class
} else{
   d3.select(this).classed("your-class-name",false); //Removing class
}
```

Or simply `d3.select(this).classed("your-class-name",d.source.x == d.target.x);`

For more details, see [D3 Class Operations](http://jaketrent.com/post/d3-class-operations/) at jaketrent.com

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use jquery selectors for that--

suppose your link contains .link class and you want to add or remove any other class eg. "your-class" then you can simply write,

```
if(d.source.x == d.target.x){
   $(".link").addClass("your-class"); //Adding class
} else{
  $(".link").removeClass("your-class");  //Removing class
}
```

D3 is simply Javascript library so it is full supported jquery.

Comment: But it select All the links and addClass. I need only for current(this) link.

Comment: current link means what are you clicking on that link?

Comment: Yes exactly, clicking or dragging link

Comment: So you can try this one. 
$(".link").click(function(){
if(d.source.x == d.target.x){
   $(this).addClass("your-class"); //Adding class
} else{
  $(this).removeClass("your-class");  //Removing class
}
})

Comment: and if @Gilsha answer is working fine then do not need to go with my answer,
Just upvote her answer dude..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74605/discussion-between-chandanwtb-and-fekkydev).